# Pros and cons of different OPCUA packages

Tags: .net, opc-ua, unified-automation-sdk

As far as I understand there are 6+ different variations of OPCUA in .NET (the 'official' .NET OPCUA, and 5+ others, such as Prosys and Unified Automation). At the moment I've tried two, the standard and Unified Automation, and found that they both have their pros and cons. So if anyone could help me understand the usecases of different OPCUA implementations in .NET, that would be great for me and I assume other beginners like me.
Thanks!

Comment: I think this question is too open-ended for StackOverflow. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140302/is-asking-open-ended-questions-allowed-on-stack-overflow.  I suggest that you rephrase your question to be more specific like how do you do X with UA?

Comment: Note: all them are paid licence except the open source version of OPC foundation.